# MySQL NodeJs - Proper way to get rows.each to work

Tags: mysql, node.js, rows, node-mysql2

When I look for simple examples, everybody's style seems quite different.  I'm tried 2 different styles, and got 2 different issues.  In the code below, I have identified the source of the code and the error it gets in comments.  I comment out or uncomment out each section and run separately, but each one has it's own errors.  The "console.log(rows); " statement is showing the data, so the query itself is running and working.

```
// get the client
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const dashline = '---------------------------------';  

console.log (dashline); 
console.log ("Starting test"); 

// create the connection to database
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'myhost',
  user: 'myuser',
  password: 'mypass',
  database: 'myDatabase'

});


console.log ("Got the database connection"); 


query = "select ID, user_nicename, user_email from wp_users where user_login = 'admin' limit 3 ";

console.log ("Starting query"); 

// Attempt 1
/*
connection.query(query, function(err, rows, fields){
  if (err) throw err;

  // from: https://html5hive.org/node-js-quickies-working-with-mysql/ 
  // error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token { (on the rows.each line below) 
  rows.each(element, index) {
    console.log(element.ID+ " " + element.user_nicename);
  }
  console.log (dashline); 
  console.log ("Query End"); 
  process.exit();   // Else Node hangs and must hit cntl-break to exit 

});
*/




// Attempt 2 

connection.query(query, function(err, rows, fields){
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(rows); 
  // Roughly based on example on this page: 
  // https://datatables.net/reference/api/each()
  // TypeError: rows.each is not a function 
  rows.each( function(element, index) {
    console.log(element.ID + " " + element.user_nicename);
  });
  console.log (dashline); 
  console.log ("The end"); 
  process.exit();   // Else Node hangs and must hit cntl-break to exit 
});
```

Comment: First off do some validation on the parameters, before use check typeof rows is an object and has a length > 0, same with fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer here: [https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/999[1].  Problem with .forEach, .each or .map is that you are inside another function which is not an async function, meaning you cannot use "await" to call another async routine.

```
for (let r=0; r < rows.length; ++r) {
  console.log(rows[r].ID + " " + rows[r].user_nicename);
  await UpdatePassword(connection, rows[r].ID);
}
```

He also provided this alternative:

One "functional" way to iterate sequentially similar to map ( imo slightly less readable then for loop ):

```
await rows.reduce( async (previousPromise, row) => {
  await previousPromise;
  return UpdatePassword(row.ID);
}, Promise.resolve());
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `.each` for Arrays doesn't exist, you should be using `.forEach(function (element, index) {...})` instead

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
  rows.forEach( function(element, index) {
    console.log(element.ID + " " + element.user_nicename);
  });
```

They are certainly similar, but there are differences. For example, "forEach" is an array method, but "$.each" can be used on any type of collection. And "forEach" is a built-in, whereas "$.each" requires loading the jQuery library.

Comment: Attempt 1 with your syntax shows: 
   rows.foreach( function(element, index) {
       ^

TypeError: rows.foreach is not a function

Attempt 2 
shows: });
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: I had a comment issue causing the unexpected token, they both give "rows.foreach is not a function".   I'm on 10.16.2 of NodeJs.

Comment: Give this a try: rows.map(e=>{ console.log(e.ID + " " + e.user_nicename);
})

Comment: Yes that worked, thanks!  Can you help me to understand why the others were wrong?  I copied them directly from blogs.  Were those blogs wrong? Or does it have to do with my version or anything else? I will read up on these as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just saw it might have been a syntax error on my part. I've edited it, can you give it a try now?

Comment: That works too.  So which is better, .forEach or .map?  I will read up on them later today hopefully.